# jQuery show hidden li elements, but then hide visible li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following jQuery code calls the `ul` element, finds the first **three** `li` list items within the element and hides the remaining `li` items. Then, it appends an `li` element which says *"Show more..."*  and, when clicked, reveals the previously hidden list items.

(jsFiddle at bottom of question)

```
$('ul')
  .find('li:gt(2)')
  .hide()
  .end()
  .append(
    $('<li>Show more...</li>').click( function(){
      $(this).siblings(':hidden').fadeIn(500);
   })
);
```

Simple enough. Now, in addition to showing the hidden list items when the user clicks *"Show more..."*, I need it to also hide the first **three** list items which are originally left visible. By illustration:

---

### *What the code currently generates:*

```
 - List Item #1
 - List Item #2
 - List Item #3
 - Show more...
```

(click)

```
 - List Item #1
 - List Item #2
 - List Item #3
 - List Item #4
 - List Item #5
 - Show more...
```

---

### *What needs to occur:*

```
 - List Item #1
 - List Item #2
 - List Item #3
 - Show more...
```

(click)

```
 - List Item #4
 - List Item #5
 - Show more...
```

---

For usability purposes, I would also be nice if when *"Show more..."* is clicked again, the first three list items become visible again and the remaining list elements are hidden.

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g9L9R/**

Comment: Side note: I tried adding `$(this).siblings(':visible').fadeOut(500);` to the code, but this ends up fading out the entire list, including List Item #4 and #5.

Comment: Ok, what if there's e.g: 30 LI's ?

Comment: @roXon There are only five li's?

Comment: The behavior is a bit odd, don't you think. Sometime "Show More" hides some elements and sometime it shows the same elements. IMO, this don't sounds very user friendly. I think "Show more" should behave in very simple way by just appending new item to the current list, which is your current behavior after all :)

Comment: @SebastienThuilliez question by OP is not asked correctly in the title

Comment: if he wants to add more li items to ul by clicking SHow More... then the question should be correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/g9L9R/7/

```
$('ul')
.find('li:gt(2)')
.hide()
.end()
.append(
  $('<li>Show more...</li>').click( function(){
  $(this).siblings().toggle(500);
})
);​
```

You will get a nice toggle effect here...

Comment: ;) well my criteria is once posted the code not to change it ever! but keep it buddy! some gentlemen here change there codes by copying others :/

Comment: will fail if list is longer than 5 items though

Answer (score 2):

```
$("li").each( function() {
if($(this).is(":visible")) {
$(this).hide();
}
else {
$(this).show();
}
});
```

and onclick of a button

```
$("button").click( function() {
$("li").each( function() {
if($(this).is(":visible")) {
$(this).hide();
}
else {
$(this).show();
}
});
});
```

Comment: well whoever downvoted please add the comments here so, i can learn from my mistakes

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
$('ul')
  .find('li:gt(2)')
  .hide()
  .end()
  .append(
    $('<li>Show more...</li>').click( function(){
      $(this).siblings(':visible').fadeOut(500);
        $(this).siblings(':hidden').fadeIn(500);
   })
);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g9L9R/4/

Comment: This would just make all elements hidden.

Comment: @Quincy well, there is no difference between codes of both of you!

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib I tried to use this code but turns out all elements went hidden! Weird :/

Comment: well the best effect and answer is the one posted by @A.V

Answer (score 1):

Solution independent of list length, hides the `more` at end

```
var list = $('ul'),
    start = 0,
    items = list.find('li').slice(0, 3).show().end(),
    more = $('<li>Show more...</li>').click(function() {
        start = start + 3
        var newItems = items.slice(start, start + 3)
        items.filter(':visible').add(newItems).toggle(500);
        if (newItems.length < 3) {
            more.hide()
        }
    }).show()
    list.append(more);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/5WgYK/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `visible` to hide the rest:

```
 $('ul')
  .find('li:gt(2)')
  .visible('hide');
```

see jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g9L9R/6/).